# Interpolating mobile signal data

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have collected the signal strengths for the mobile operator at some places in my college campus. Now I want to spatially interpolate this data for the entire campus. I am using PostGIS.

I am planning to use the Inverse Distance Weighting (IDW) method for the interpolation. Can someone guide me how can I employ this by using PostGIS. Are there any inbuilt functions available or will I have to write the separate algorithm for this.

Comment: please make this question answerable by providing what you do know, and have tried. maybe resources you are familiar with and capability you have (software/program lang etc)

Answer (score 2):

I would highly recommend a literature search before embarking on an IDW approach. A colleague of mine has a few papers on dual-phase sampling of cellular signals using Kriging. Because cellular signals are a highly nonstationary spatial process, an IDW approach is not appropriate. Whereas Kriging can have a model term to account for 2nd order effects as well as anisotropy (directional variation), which is also certainly present in the data.

To directly address you question, I would aim you towards [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/), which can read PostGIS data. Because of access to SAGA and GRASS, There are several interpolation methods available including: IDW, Kriging, Spline, TIN, Natural Neighbors...

Here are a few citations to get you started

Delmelle E.M. and P. Goovaerts (2009). Second-Phase Sampling Designs for
Non-Stationary Spatial Variables. Geoderma, vol. 153: 205-216

Rogerson P., Delmelle E.M., Batta R., Akella M., Blatt A. and G. Wilson (2004).
Optimal Sampling Design for Variables with Varying Spatial Importance.
Geographical Analysis, vol. 36: 177-194

Delmelle E.M. (2013). Model-based criteria for second-phase spatial sampling. in Mateu, J. and Muller, W.G. Spatio-Temporal Design, Wiley.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jeffrey! You mean I should go with QGIS for interpolation. Cant we do it without using QGIS, by querying or by using python/JAVA code?